# Deploy via GitHub

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I am doing this course on HTML, CSS, and Javascript for Web Developers on Coursera, as I am new to all this, and I have stumbled upon something that I think is very old information in the course, and not working anymore with the same tools as they have changed over time. So in this course we have the GitHub pages tool, which at that time could be used simply via the "deploy" button. Right now, the GitHub pages tool is disabled unless you create a branch, and it offers this GitHub Actions option under Build and Development, from where you can choose different workflows. By choosing any of them, you get the site deployed, but upon entering it, it gives 404 error. From my understanding, what's missing is the index.html file. How can you use the GitHub Actions tool to also have the index.html file and get rid of the error?

I have tried deploying from a branch, but I am missing valuable information on how to make that work.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75409546/edit) your question and include your workflow along with all the relevant information such as links that you followed, branch names, etc.Thanks!

Comment: It's not so clear what need to do the GitHub action. Do you want to use some available template on GitHub?